# Convert a character vector to POSIXct format

Tags: r

Hi I am fairly new to R and I am looking into converting a character vector to DateTime format. The character vector consists of year, month, date, hours, mins, secs without any separators. I can't seem to figure out how to do the conversion. I tried using function anytime(), anydate() from "anytime" but it only retains the date and the time is lost.

My data looks like:

```
head(d)
  Cam_number          Date1          Date2
1   Camera01 20190913235959 20190914000115
2   Camera02 20190913235959 20190914000115
3   Camera01 20190914000248 20190914000115
4   Camera02 20190914000248 20190914000115
5   Camera01 20190914000309 20190914000115
6   Camera02 20190914000309 20190914000115
```

Date1 is the date and time the video started and Date1 is the date and time end.

I want to have an output which will have 4 columns, ie, Cam_number, Date, Start time, End time

Comment: `lubridate::ymd_hms(20190913235959)` OR `lubridate::ymd_hms("20190913235959")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `as.POSIXct` and `format`.

```
res <- `colnames<-`(cbind(dat[1], mapply(function(x, y) 
  format(as.POSIXct(x, format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), format=y), dat[c(2, 2, 3)], 
  c("%Y-%m-%d", rep("%H:%M:%S", 2)))), 
  c("Cam_number", "Date", "Start time", "End time"))
res
#   Cam_number       Date Start time End time
# 1   Camera01 2019-09-13   23:59:59 00:01:15
# 2   Camera02 2019-09-13   23:59:59 00:01:15
# 3   Camera01 2019-09-14   00:02:48 00:01:15
# 4   Camera02 2019-09-14   00:02:48 00:01:15
# 5   Camera01 2019-09-14   00:03:09 00:01:15
# 6   Camera02 2019-09-14   00:03:09 00:01:15
```

However, that what you want is no `POSIXct` format. Instead you may want to consider:

```
res2 <- cbind(dat[1], 
              setNames(data.frame(lapply(dat[-1], as.POSIXct, format="%Y%m%d%H%M%S")),
                       c("Start time", "End time")))
res2
#   Cam_number               Date1               Date2
# 1   Camera01 2019-09-13 23:59:59 2019-09-14 00:01:15
# 2   Camera02 2019-09-13 23:59:59 2019-09-14 00:01:15
# 3   Camera01 2019-09-14 00:02:48 2019-09-14 00:01:15
# 4   Camera02 2019-09-14 00:02:48 2019-09-14 00:01:15
# 5   Camera01 2019-09-14 00:03:09 2019-09-14 00:01:15
# 6   Camera02 2019-09-14 00:03:09 2019-09-14 00:01:15
```

where

```
lapply(res2, class)
# $Cam_number
# [1] "character"
# 
# $Date1
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
# 
# $Date2
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(Cam_number = c("Camera01", "Camera02", "Camera01", 
"Camera02", "Camera01", "Camera02"), Date1 = c("20190913235959", 
"20190913235959", "20190914000248", "20190914000248", "20190914000309", 
"20190914000309"), Date2 = c("20190914000115", "20190914000115", 
"20190914000115", "20190914000115", "20190914000115", "20190914000115"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6"))
```